# Concatenate a two dimensional array

Tags: javascript, matrix, multidimensional-array, concatenation, string-concatenation

I'm new, and I need help to find the right solution for my function in javascript:

```
function concatenateMatrix(matrix) { }
var stringMatrix = [
    ['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'],
    [' ', 'J', 'a', 'v', 'a'],
    ['W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '!']
];
var matrix = '';
newArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < stringMatrix.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < stringMatrix[i].length; j++);
    newArray.push(stringMatrix);
    stringMatrix = '';
}
console.log(concatenateMatrix(stringMatrix))
```

`Hello , Java World!` should be displayed.

What did I do wrong? Thanks a lot.

Edit: I have solved it. Thanks a lot.

```
for (var x in stringMatrix) {
    if (stringMatrix[x] instanceof Array) {
        stringMatrix[x] = stringMatrix[x].join("");
    }
}
var concatenateMatrix = stringMatrix.join("");

return concatenateMatrix;
```

Comment: `console.log(concatenateMatrix(stringMatrix)) ` is javascript

Comment: This looks like JavaScript and not Java. Are you playing with Nashorn to run JavaScript on JVM?

Comment: sorry of course jacascript and i use repl.it

Comment: @TR54296 not jacascript it's javascript

Comment: sorry my finger was to fast ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answers. But it must work with the  console.log(concatenateMatrix(stringMatrix)); so thats why i will concate the arrays and push it

Answer (score 0):

You can first flatten/merge the array elements and then [**`join`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) then with `""` to show the full word like

```
[].concat.apply([], stringMatrix).join("")
```

```js
var stringMatrix = [
['H','e','l','l','o'],
[' ','J','a','v','a'],
['W','o','r','l','d','!']
];

console.log([].concat.apply([], stringMatrix).join(""))
```

Comment: This is beautiful! @George Bailey

Comment: Thanks @AjitBalachandran :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function matrixMapper(matrix){
  var str = ''
  matrix.map(function(arr){
    str += arr.join('') + ' '
  })
console.log(str)
}
```

Basically iterate over the arrays in the matrix, join the subarrays and add them to your string

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), [`concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) and [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)method of array.

**DEMO**

```js
var arr= [
['H','e','l','l','o'],
[' ','J','a','v','a'],
['W','o','r','l','d','!']
];

console.log(arr.reduce((r,v)=>r.concat(v),[]).join(''));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

---

Using [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
var arr= [
['H','e','l','l','o'],
[' ','J','a','v','a'],
['W','o','r','l','d','!']
];

console.log(arr.map(v=>v.join('')).join(''));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Buddy,
I think you are new to javaScript you can achieve your goal using single array only, don't need to use two loops and two array. I have checked your code write little bit code for you try to

```
 var stringMatrix = ['H','e','l','l','o',' ','J','a','v','a','W','o','r','l','d','!'];
        for(var i=0; i<stringMatrix.length; i++){    
            document.write(stringMatrix[i]);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

since everybody pointed out easier ways of doing that, but you have very concerning flaws in your code writing, here is a simple correction of **your** code :

```
function concatenateMatrix(matrix) {
    var stringMatrix = [
        ['H','e','l','l','o'],
        [' ','J','a','v','a'],
        ['W','o','r','l','d','!']
    ];
    var matrix = '';
    newArray = [];
    for(var i=0; i<stringMatrix.length; i++){
        for(var j=0; j<stringMatrix[i].length; j++){
            newArray.push(stringMatrix[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return newArray;
}
console.log(concatenateMatrix(stringMatrix));
```

you closed too early your curly braces, code with indentation so you can see theese problems,
you missed the return value,
you were adding `stringMatrix` instead of `stringMatrix[i][j]`,
and you were clearing your `stringMatrix` every time in your `i` loop (maybe you wanted to clear `stringMatrix[i]` instead ?)

Answer (score 0):

You can concat the arrays and then Join the final array with Join function of arrays.

```
var str=[]; 
for(var i=0;i<stringMatrix.length;i++){ 
  str = str.concat(stringMatrix[i]);
}
console.log(str.join(" "));
```